# Use of Hidden Markov Models for Clustering

Tags: clustering, hidden-markov-model

I would like to ask whether Hidden Markov Models can be used for clustering and if so, in what cases.

I have found somewhere, references like this but practically I haven't found a way to do this. Is it possible with matlab?

Here http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hidden-markov-models-hmm.html#f10382  we can see only how to analyze HMMs.

I have worked once with HMM in order to predict the next possible data in a sequence of data.

The training of the model gave some distributions for the data/observations for each state.

We could say in a way that the states correspond to clusters, but what I am thinking is that one sequence of data/observations may come from a sequence of states.

What I need is to assign a sequence of data in a unique state or cluster. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.44.3648

Comment: Very very interesting and absolutely relevant! I guess this is the solution to my problem. Do you know whether there exists an example online applying the algorithm perhaps in matlab or elsewhere? Otherwise I suppose have to study it thoroughly step by step and then try to develop a script applying all the steps.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am not very familiar yet with most of the literature and freely available software packages in that sub-field.

Comment: Don't worry, thank you very much anyway.